# Получить рандомное число между [1, 2 ,3], но не в отрезке от min до max

Tags: javascript, случайные-числа

Задача такая

- если я выбираю в массиве `[1, 2, 3]` число `1`, то нужно получить рандомом `2` или `3`.
- если я выберу `2`, то нужно получить рандомом `1` или `3`.
- и , если я выберу `3`, то нужно получить рандомом `1` или `2`.

Как это сделать?

Comment: Выбрасываете из массива выбранное, получаете случайное из остатка...

Comment: Альтернативный вариант - выбираете случайное, проверяете. если равно выбранному, повторяете... когда-нить, да повезёт.

Comment: @Akina ахахах, господи , точно. Так все просто, спасибо большое за ответ!

Comment: Для того, кто только что всем поставил минус - объясните свои минусы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализация "альтернативного варианта", предложенным [Akina](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1004230/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-1-2-3-%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82-min-%D0%B4%D0%BE-max#comment1700972_1004230):

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3]; // массив
var index = 2; // исключаемый индекс
var rand = Math.round(Math.random()*(2 - 0 + 0) + 0); // берем рандом от 0 до 2
while(rand == index){ // пока у нас рандом равен исключаемому индексу
  rand = Math.round(Math.random()*(2 - 0 + 0) + 0); // берем рандом от 0 до 2
}
console.log(array[rand]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let array = [1,2,3]; //объявляем массив
const remove_index = 1; //указываем удаляемый индекс
array = array.filter((el, i) => i!==1); //удаляем
console.log(array[Math.round(Math.random())]); //вытаскиваем случайное значение
```